# Apache Isis using Wicket Viewer 8

Tags: apache, user-interface, customization, wicket, isis

Hello Apache Isis users,

i prototyped a Apache Isis Webapp.

i would like to use the component Apache Wicket 8 instead of the default Wicket Viewer in Apache Isis Framework.

It is generally possible to exchange the Apache Wicket Viewer with Apache Wicket 8?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Isis provides a viewer based on Apache Wicket, i.e. Isis uses basic Wicket components to build more sophisticated ones for its needs.

You can replace Isis' components (actually Wicket Panels and Pages) with custom ones if you need via its [ComponentFactory](http://isis.apache.org/guides/ugvw/ugvw.html#_ugvw_extending_replacing-page-elements).

To upgrade Wicket to v.8 you can add `wicket-core`, `wicket-extensions` and `wicket-auth-roles` dependencies to your `pom.xml` (or build.gradle, ...), i.e. you can override the version used by Apache Isis. But I cannot guarantee that it will just work. It is an upgrade of a major dependency version so there might be some obstacles. You should consult with Wicket's [migration guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+8.0) if you face issues.

AFAIK Isis v.2 (work in progress) is using Wicket 8.x, so you may use its milestone releases.

Comment: Definitely you should use 2.0.0-M1.  We are looking to put out an M2 soon, but that doesn't substantially how the wicket viewer works.